# Replace a image resource URl with my domain address

Tags: dns, redirect, namecheap

I don't know how exactly to explain my question.

I have a URL of image: `http://hostimages.com/flower/images1.jpg`. Now I want to replace this **hostimages.com** with my domain **myhost.com**. So the new URL will be like `http://myhost.com/flower/images1.jpg`

Is it possible to setup mydomain DNS like this? I already tried with CNAME and URL redirect, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not host the image on your web host and to access it via the domain the other way I can think of is to create URL redirect, but with a path saving option, this way when you ask for `http://myhost.com/flower/images1.jpg` you will get `http://myhost.com/flower/images1.jpg`, but have in mind that you would probably need to create the redirect for a subdomain, if you have another service (like a web site) using `http://myhost.com`.

So probably it will be okay to create the redirect for `images.myhost.com` or `resources.myhost.com`